# Conflict in gms:play-service and firebase-ml-vision library implementation for different version

Tags: android

I am using 
implementation `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'`
in my project and now I have to add barcode reader functionality in my app so I add

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
```

Now when I run my project It gives error **"cannot access Hide"**

Comment: Use same version as play service

Comment: But play service version is not available for ml-vision and vise versa

Comment: try this, may be it will solve your problem. "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2"

Comment: refer this - https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup and https://developers.google.com/vision/android/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I was getting conflicting libraries error, so I added this line which solved for me:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3`

so you'll have both:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
```